# Get data from native process on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, native, output, progress

I´m converting a video with my app, and I got it using the FFmpeg library. I´m using a static compiled version of FFmpeg and I run my command like this:

```
        //Conversion video
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("data/data/package/cache/ffmpeg -i "   path   " -g "   String.valueOf(keyFrames)   " -s 720x480 -vcodec libx264 -an -y /sdcard/lowResolution.mp4");
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Video convertido");
```

It works well but it takes me too much time, so I would like to put a progress bar, so I should need to read output events of the process (the same output I can see when I execute the command in terminal) in order to know how long will it take or something like that.

Sorry for my english and thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

You put the whole thing inside a thread (or maybe AsyncTask, depends upon your preference):

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //Conversion video
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("data/data/package/cache/ffmpeg -i "   path   " -g "   String.valueOf(keyFrames)   " -s 720x480 -vcodec libx264 -an -y /sdcard/lowResolution.mp4");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()  {
                        //update ur progress dialog accordingly
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Video convertido");
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't help me... I need the video converted before continue working, so creating a new thread won´t work...

Comment: There is an Android Logcat app that do the same thing https://code.google.com/p/alogcat/source/browse/trunk/src/org/jtb/alogcat/Logcat.java I edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Well, I don´t know how to use this code. Is "line" the string with the last output? I'm not getting any output...